# OpenSSH Port Forwarding Remotely

Tags: 14.04, openssh, port-forwarding

I have the ff: setup

Server : Ubuntu 14.04 (192.168.1.102) openssh server & client installed

Router : Lynksys E1000 Port forwarded added ( ssh - 20-80 both 192.168.1.102 )

Now in another unit but same network with the server i can ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.102 (working) But when remotely it's not working ssh ubuntu@router-public-ip-address

Will someone help me with this one? Did I miss some configuration or something?

Additional Info :
Network Setup : Modem - Router - Hub - Server

Comment: Ssh is port 22, go to canyouseeme .com and check that port

Comment: @wlraider70 canyouseeme. org says I could not see your service on (IP) on port (22)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your ISP does [Carrier-grade NAT](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). In some of these cases you will never be able to host a service because of the NAT part that is not under your control but the ISP. I have found that some providers detect if customers have port forwarding active and try to host services on their boxes, after some time (a few days) of leaving your router configured properly you may be able to connect remotely.

If the is the first time you are trying to configure something with this connection/router ask your ISP what their policy is. Or use IPv6 if it is available.